# Even after logging out user, clicking back will show user their previous page. 

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, iphone

I have couple of pages on my mobile web site. One page lets user log in and the other show user their date and lets user log out. However, when user is logged out and redirected to the login page they can click on back button and get back to the page where they supposedly authenticated.

I just have one html page divided into multiple divs ("pages")  and using `$.mobile.changePage` to navigate from one page to another.

How can I make it so that when user does click on back button they don't see their data?

When I browse back my 'pageinit' doesn't get executed. If it was I would be able to check if the user is logged in...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/GF8np/5/

JS

```
var $secure_token = true;

$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    // Check for secure token here
    if($secure_token != true) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#login", { transition: "slideup"} );
    }
});

// Act if user has logged out
$('#secure2').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    $secure_token = false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Redirect</li>
            <li><a href="#secure1">Secure Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#secure2">Secure Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secure1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Secure Page 1</li>
            <li><a href="#secure2">Secure Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secure2">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Please hit the browser back button or right click and back</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal behaviour, as any browser saves the previous webpage it rendered. I just tested with my own webpage, and it indeed shows the info, but whenever you try and change something, the system redirects to the login view.

I mean, they will see the previous data, but it will be stale, and they won't be able to change it without login in first.